# Storing data in an array of char*

Tags: c, arrays

My task is to store data in an array of char* in main(), and  each row of the data being in its own string. I am suppose to hard-code the given data. Is this the right way to do it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int i;

    char* numbers[5] {"12, 34, 56, 78",
                      "82.16, 41.296",
         "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
        "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9"};
    for(i=0;i<5;i++){
    //print//
    }


}
```

Comment: Your array has a length of 5 but only has 4 elements.

Comment: If you replace `char *numbers[5] = ...` with `char *numbers[] = ...` the compiler figures out the size of the array automatically. Incidentally, it'll be less than `5` in this case, which also means your `for()`-loop has incorrect bounds.

Comment: I thought that would help with the loop later on.

Comment: It will help with a segmentation fault later on or garbage values.

Comment: awesome i'll do that.

Comment: Then the for loop should be like this                                               for(i=0;i<MAX;i++){
    //print//
    }

Comment: If you're asking if you should use named constants instead of magic numbers, then yes. Otherwise, that will result in error as well, since you haven't declared or initialized `MAX`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
char* numbers[5] {"12, 34, 56, 78",
                  "82.16, 41.296",
                  "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
                  "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9"};
```

You forget the `=`

And there are only 4 strings in your array, change to

```
char *numbers[] = {"12, 34, 56, 78",
                   "82.16, 41.296",
                   "2, -3, 5, -7, 11, -13, 17, -19",
                   "9.00009, 90.0009, 900.009, 9000.09, 90000.9"};
```

And here

```
for(i=0;i<5;i++){
```

Don't use magic numbers like `5`, instead, use the `sizeof` operator in order to get the correct size:

```
for (i = 0; i < (sizeof numbers / sizeof *numbers); i++){
```

Comment: Good catch on the `=`'s

Comment: I appreciate you awesome people.